# CSS3 and Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a Navigation bar that has [this style](http://karsonbeckstead.com/images/header/navigation%20bar,%20all/navbar.png) with drop down menu style, i have got my menu as layed out  here

```
<nav>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/kbi/articles/articles.php">Articles</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/kbi/articles/new/new.php">News & Updates</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/kbi/articles/reviews/reviews.php">Reviews</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/kbi/articles/toppicks/toppicks.php">Top Picks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/kbi/articles/vault/thevault.php">Vault</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/kbi/articles/myrig.php">My Rig</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="kbi/devices/devices.php">Devices</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/kbi/devices/android/android.php">Android</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/kbi/devices/ios/ios.php">IOS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/kbi/devices/windows/windows.php">Windows</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/kbi/devices/osx/osx.php">OSX</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/kbi/devices/linux/linux.php">Linux</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/kbi/about/about.php">About</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/kbi/about/contact/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                        <ul>
                            <a href="/kbi/articles/myrig.php">My Rig</a>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

and my CSS to go along with it

```
nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
background: #efefef; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
nav ul li {
float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
    nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
    nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 15px 40px;
        color: #fff;
    }   
        nav ul ul li a:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
        }
nav ul ul ul {
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

but it doesnt span the whole length of the page, what can i do differently?

Comment: Why would you want a navigation that looks like that?!

Comment: I recommend using something like "bootstrap" for doing something like this. What you are trying to do requires javascript and can look unclean. Bootstrap can do all of this for you really quickly. check it out [link](getbootstrap.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your styles `nav ul` element is `display: inline-table`, so it takes as much horizontal space as needed. Make it `block` level element to span entire width:

```
nav ul {
    background: #efefef;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: block; /* make it block */
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/e0ar7urh/1/

Comment: thank you that worked well, this is a school project so i am trying to do the code all myself. thanks!

Comment: Good luck with the project! Feel free to accept the answer if it helped.